# How to add line breaks to prevent overly long lines?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just read the best practices of Python scripts. I found recommended length should not exceed 80 characters per line.

So in my script more than  100 characters are exist.

I have break the lines and below are examples.

- Example 1

  ```
  self.remote_conn_pre.connect("self.hostname, "
      "username=self.username, password=self.password, "
       "look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False")
  ```
- Example 2

  ```
   self.remote_conn.send(""create bigdata\n" "
      " .format(pending.upper(), (total) + 9)")
  ```
- Example 3

  ```
   print ("This is the first line of my text {} "
   "which will be joined to a second {}.".format(a,b))
  ```

Could any one please correct me if I am doing anything wrong and help me determine the best ways to break long lines into small lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use docstrings and escape the newline character.

```
print ("""
This is the first line of my text {} \
which will be joined to a second {}.
""").format(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python supports splitting up lines using the backslash `\` character, like so:

```
d = "one two three " \
    "four five six"

print d
```

Prints `one two three four five six`